# Message Composer like Twitter/Facebook

Tags: ios, user-interface, twitter, uinavigationbar

Is there any third party libraries or an easy way of creating a message composer (I don't really know what to call it) like the one in the image attached?

It should have the camera and album buttons, as well as an extra one for another option, with the keyboard always showing except when you push the options above. So it is just like the Twitter app.

[image]

Here, we need exact transitions as how twitter composer handles when sliding album view up and down.

Comment: it will be easier to customize a view controller like this an present it when you need it.

Comment: @CharanGiri I designed it myself like you said, with some limitations since I am pretty new with xcode, but it works perfectly, thanks!